# Powerset - smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

could You explain why the following code is wrong:

```
powerset
     |ps|
     ps := Set with: (Set new).
     self do: [:item | ps addToPowerSet: item].
    ^ps

addToPowerSet: elt
    | first second third var |
    first := self copy.  
    second := self copy.  
    third := Set new.
    second do:  [:item | var := item copy. var add: elt. third add: var.].
    ^ first addAll: third
```

Both methods are implemented in Set class.
I have tried to debug it and I suppose that the mistake is here:

```
second do:  [:item | var := item copy. var add: elt. third add: var.].
```

But I have no idea what precisely.

Ok, example to addToPowerSet method:

Let's assumet that powerset variable ps is equal:

```
{{empty}, {a}, {b}, {a,b}}
```

and item = c.
addToPowerSet method should return:

```
{
    {empty}, {a}, {b}, {a,b},
    {c}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a,b,c}
}
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: What smalltalk are you using? What is your expected result?

Comment: @camillobruni I am using Dolphin Smalltalk X6

Comment: @Marcin Powerset is a method inside Set class. I am sending powerset message to set (like this: 'Set withAll: #(1 2 3)) powerset'. As an answer I would like to obtain powerset (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of this set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not really familiar with the formatting in stackoverflow, but isn't the problem that your returning a new set every time you call addToPowerSet: ? 
This seems to work:

```
    addToPowerSet: elt
| second third var |
second := self copy.
third := Set new.
second do: 
        [:item |
        var := item copy.
        var add: elt.
        third add: var].
^self addAll: third
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two problems with your design, such that *what you want is wrong*:

1. For `c addToPowerSet` to work on any object, you would have to add it to `Object`.
2. The expression `c addToPowerSet` does not refer to a powerset.

What you *should* do is create a subclass of `Set`, which overrides the `add:` method, or on `Set` add a method `addToPowerset:` which should handle the case that the receiver is not a powerset.